# What's wrong with this contenteditable div?

Tags: html, focus, cursor, contenteditable

In creating this webtop app, I've created stacks of contenteditable divs exactly like this one, which is part of a homemade widget.  But for some reason this one isn't working.

```
<div class="draft combobox" title="Draft"> 
  <ul> 
    <li> 
    </li>
  </ul>
<div class="text" contentEditable="true">   <!-- Right Here -->
<img class="arrow button" src="icons/scroll-down-white.png" />
```

Now just a little background around the issue.  I am in the process of rewriting the html, well turning it into haml anyway (with Phamlp).  It was just getting too illegible.  I'm also using lessphp on the css.

These are the only changes I've made.  The output remains the same, only now the contenteditable div doesn't work... It accepts focus, but there's no cursor... and no response to key events.

Also I'm yet to attach any javascript to it.  So there's nothing going on there that could be hindering it.

So what's wrong with this div!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I worked it out... turned out that I had '-webkit-user-select:none' set in the css on an ancestor div!